# max values for different id_groups in one table

Tags: mysql

i have the following table

```
id, id_group, somenumber
-------------------------
1   0         15
2   1         3
3   0         25 
4   1         14
5   2         63
```

Is it possible with one query to make such result?

```
    id_group, maxnumber
    --------------------
    0         63
    1         14
    2         63
```

Please note that in the resulting table for id_group=0 I need to get maximum number from all three groups from source table not just id_group=0

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT id_group, MAX(somenumber)
FROM Table1
WHERE id_group <> 0
GROUP BY id_group
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 id_group, MAX(somenumber)
FROM Table1
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd91a/3)

Comment: Thanks, that was fast, looks nice, will give it a try, will this construction be fast enough to be included as INNER JOIN (yourselect) AS B in another much bigger SELECT?

Comment: And another thing - what does this construction do - SELECT 0 fieldname? Haven't used it before. Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT 0 fieldname` would select 0 as a constant value, instead of a field value.

Comment: Ah, alright, was used to syntax like SELECT 0 AS fieldname that's why i got confused, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I propose you do the following :-

```
SELECT id_group, MAX(somenumber) FROM `table` GROUP BY id_group;
```

Comment: yes, that would be correct if i would not need to get max number for group 0 from all three groups (0,1,2) :)